# How to check whether a class is the successor of another class?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a code:

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle();
console.log(circle instanceof Kinetic.Node); // false
```

But result is `false`;

How to check whether a class `Kinetic.Circle` inherits the class `Kinetic.Node`?

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic does not use real prototypical inheritance, it uses a `extend`-method which passes the prototypical functions but no prototype object. This is why `instanceof` returns `false`.
You can test for `Kinetic.Shape` by using:

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle();
console.log( circle.nodeType === "Shape" ); //returns true
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tohos/1/edit)

Edit: if you really need to test for `Kinetic.Node`, i would use something like `object.hasOwnProperty("nodeType");`

Edit2: If you want to inherit classes from `Kinetic.Circle` i would use prototypical inheritance, which will grant you access via `instanceof`:

```
var Circle = function( c ) { Kinetic.Circle.call( this, c ); };
Circle.prototype = Object.create( Kinetic.Circle );
var inst = new Circle( );
console.log( inst instanceof Circle ); // true
console.log( inst instanceof Kinetic.Circle ); //true
// use Circle or create subclasses of Circle
```

If you really want to use `Kinetic.Util.extend` use something similar to `nodeType`:

```
var Circle = function( c ) { Kinetic.Circle.call( this, c ); this.myType = "MyCircle" };
Kinetic.Util.extend( Circle, Kinetic.Circle );

var inst = new Circle( );
console.log( inst.myType === "MyCircle" ); //true
```

Comment: I inherit all my objects with function Kinetic.Util.extend,can create an array of all superclasses inside the function Kinetis.util.extend, such as can be done? Need an analog operator "is" used in other languages